# how to implement checksum check logic on server for jar identification whether they are same or updated one

Tags: java, shell, powershell

I have to implement checksum logic for the deployed jar on the server.Whenever we go for deployment on server, first it should check whether there are changes in the jar that we are going to deploy or its same.This logic I have to implement for my application.Matching of jars that we have to deploy with the already deployed jar on the server should be achieved via any checksum implementation like MD5 etc.It is a stand alone application for which I have to do this. which has around 100+ jar files to deploy. Please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Get-Help Get-FileHash

Comment: @SimonVerhoeven   I was just looking for process..so not able to find much ..not able to understand how to approach for this.

Comment: @LotPings  am sorry I didnot get it..

Comment: That's a powershell cmdlet to do a hash. This is a programmers site, reading manuals/help and doing research is a prerequisite ´. with get-filehash you create hashes of both sides you might compare with compare-object

Comment: @LotPings  thanks..even the same we can do via simple cmd as well using some java commands..that I have done..But I want to automate it and want to make it execute on servers before deploying any jar file of the application..

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to add this to whatever is doing the deployment to the servers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, its pretty straightforward

Here is a simple setup, but should get the point across

I have 3 jar files in c:\temp:

- c:\temp\jce.jar
- c:\temp\management-agent.jar
- c:\temp\resources.jar

Run `Get-FileHash` for each trusted jar file and save the hash for each

```
$fh1 = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -LiteralPath "c:\temp\jce.jar"
$fh2 = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -LiteralPath "c:\temp\management-agent.jar"
$fh3 = Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 -LiteralPath "c:\temp\resources.jar"

write-host ("hash for " + (Split-Path $fh1.Path -Leaf) + " is " + $fh1.Hash)
write-host ("hash for " + (Split-Path $fh2.Path -Leaf) + " is " + $fh2.Hash)
write-host ("hash for " + (Split-Path $fh3.Path -Leaf) + " is " + $fh3.Hash)
```

Output:

```
hash for jce.jar is 105840A8B3AB7FF368D58ABA76B83EB0EA5445A4FE6F84A4ACE9A3C8F05CB9E9
hash for management-agent.jar is 08F3CFCCC50A1975B38B61E8F0409A96C8067C8DB3001694244F58927C1CC2BB
hash for resources.jar is BD7734192A891EBA585E94996C4A8812F7CF96753671AA9A74268C39FAF50987
```

Run the same program on the same jars on the server (adjusting the paths as necessary). Verify that each hash matches.